# sympy.plotting.plot3d don't plot constant functions

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

This code

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot3d
x, y = symbols("x y")

f = lambda x, y: x * y
plot3d((f(x,y), (x, -3, 3), (y, -3, 3)))

g = lambda x, y: 2
plot3d((g(x,y), (x, -3, 3), (y, -3, 3)))
```

plot first graphic, but not second with error

> ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it doesn't plot constant functions yet. The line which raises the `ValueError` should be changed to allow constants - if there is a constant, make an array here that is filled with just that value instead of raising an Exception. You could fix it and submit a pull request to them!

```py
        if Z.ndim != 2:
            raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
        # TODO: Support masked arrays
        X, Y, Z = np.broadcast_arrays(X, Y, Z)
        rows, cols = Z.shape
```

Here is a hacky solution which may work for your purposes. I define a delta which is very small, and use a function of the temporary variables `_x` and `_y` so it stays symbolic.

The other change I have made is to use functions instead of lambda expressions, because you define them in the code.

Also, by plotting `f` and `g` in the same `plot3d` call, it plots them both on the same axes. Otherwise it will only plot the first one.

```py
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot3d
import numpy as np
x, y = symbols("x y")


def f(_x, _y):
    return np.multiply(_x, _y)


def g(_x, _y):
    delta = 0.00000000000000001
    return (_x - delta)/_x + (_y - delta)/_y

plot3d((f(x, y), (x, -3, 3), (y, -3, 3)), (g(x, y), (x, -3, 3), (y, -3, 3)))
```

[image: This is the output of the approximate solution]

Comment: The line that raises the error is in matplotlib. Matplotlib will not allow scalars. So if anything this should be fixed in sympy. But seen from [this issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5642), it's not as easy as one might think.